# Why i have to use foo() instead of function foo() in classes?

Tags: javascript

Why i have to use foo() instead of function foo() in classes?

```
class car {
  move() {
    console.log("move")
  }
}
let a = new car()
a.move()

function move() {
  console.log("move")
}
move()
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uydr1vhd/2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that's just how the `class` syntax is designed. Those are *method declarations*, not function declarations (methods are functions, but with access to `super` and an unbreakable link to the object they were created as part of, their [[[HomeObject]]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#table-16)). While it would have been possible to design the syntax to require the `function` keyword, it would have been verbose, unnecessary, and arguably misleading; so TC39 (the committee behind moving JavaScript forward) decided not to include it.

---

Side note: You can also use method syntax in an object initializer, but unlike a `class` body, it's like any other property declaration in that you have to separate it from other properties with a comma:

```
const o = {
    foo() {
        // ...
    },                // <=== Note the comma
    bar() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Whereas those commas would be syntax errors in a class body, which would look like this:

```
class Example {
    foo() {
        // ...
    }
    bar() {
        // ...
    }
}
```